# SSIS Excel Validation Failed Error

Tags: sql-server, excel, validation, ssis

I am loading excel to sql server database table. I am facing the below error on excel source validation failed.

Error: 0xC004700C at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: One or more component failed validation.
Error: 0xC0024107 at Data Flow Task: There were errors during task validation.
Warning: 0x80019002 at Infinite loop: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (4) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
Warning: 0x80019002 at Package: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (4) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
SSIS package "G:\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ReportAutomation\ReportAutomation\Package.dtsx" finished: Failure.
The program '[14472] DtsDebugHost.exe: DTS' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

I tried making the Debugging section RUN64bit Runtime to FALSE and also Delay validation to TRUE. Still i am facing this issue. Please help me.

Comment: Unfortunately SSIS errors are very verbose. All that tells you is there  was an error. You need to dig a but further in the logs to find the actual error. Often this is because the file is not accessible

Comment: Close the excel file you are trying to read using ssis

Comment: follow the steps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15861808/failed-to-import-excel-to-sql-server-using-ssis-package

Comment: I can't keep the data here it's client data...I am facing this issue in real-time data.